# Unmount volume, and dependent mounts

Tags: mount, devices, bind, unmount, umount

I explain:

Currently I have:

A volume mounted to a directory, /mountDirectory
And I also have a local directory that has a mount bind to a directory on the volume:
/localDirectory mount bind /mountDirectory/directory2
this way from /localDirectory I can see the content as if it were /mountDirectory/directory2

I want to umount the volume, so that /localDirectory is also umounted.

It's possible?

Currently if I do umount /dev/volume, doing lsblk shows me the volume mounted in /localDirectory.

Comment: Why not simply do a symbolic link from `/localDirectory` to `/mountDirectory/directory2` instead of a double mount?

Comment: I need it to be mount bind

Answer (score 0):

try with `sudo umount /mountDirectory/directory2` and then `sudo umount /mountDirectory`